# Make return from S3 indexing function "[" invisible

Tags: r

Is it possible to return an invisible object when using the S3 indexing function "[" on a custom class? For example, in the code below, is there a way to make the last line of code not print anything?

```
mat <- function(x) {
  structure(x, class="mat")
}

"[.mat" <- function(x, i, j) {
  invisible(unclass(x)[i,j])
}

m1 <- mat(matrix(1:10, ncol=2))
m1[1:2,]

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    6
[2,]    2    7
```

Comment: I don't know anything about making classes, but yours seems malformed. `str(m1)` works fine before defining `"[.mat"` but gives an error afterwards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the value returned from `[.mat` is not of class `mat` since you're using `unclass`, so it uses the default printing method for whatever class it has. To fix this, just ensure that the returned object is still a `mat` and define a printing method for `mat` objects.

```
mat <- function(x) {
    class(x) <- "mat"
    x
}

`[.mat` <- function(x, i, j) {
    y <- mat(unclass(x)[i, j])
    invisible(y)
}

print.mat <- function(x, ...) {
    invisible(x)
}

test <- mat(matrix(1:10, ncol = 2))

test[1, 1]
# Nothing is printed
```

Comment: Still prints for me on R-3.2.0 on 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior you describe (R3.1.2), I still get output with your code.  Also, I'm not sure I agree with your logic.

Comment: Does not work for me either. But after adding `"print.mat" <- function(x,...) {}` to @Alex A. 's code it does.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich: Fixed. Forgot to add the print method. :(

Comment: @cryo111: Yes, thank you. I had inadvertently omitted that from my post.

Comment: There is still something weird here.  You shouldn't have to define a print method for this to return invisibly.

Comment: @BrodieG: But when you just type an object in the REPL, isn't `print` being implicitly called?

Comment: @BrodieG: Completely agree. Especially since `test_fun=function(x,i,j) {invisible(unclass(x[i,j]))};test_fun(m1,1,1);` works without those hacks. Is `invisible` handled differently in ordinary functions and S3 methods?

Comment: @AlexA. the `invisible` value should still be respected.  There are also some other corner cases that I can't recall right now that strongly suggest that the REPL stuff is not as simple as `eval(print(expr))`, though in most cases it appears equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

You are running into issues with the visibility mechanism caused by primitive functions.  Consider:

```
> length.x <- function(x) invisible(23)
> length(structure(1:10, class="x"))
[1] 23
> mean.x <- function(x) invisible(23)
> mean(structure(1:10, class="x"))
> # no output
```

`length` is a primitive, but `mean` is not.  From **[R Internals](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html#Autoprinting)**:

> Whether the returned value of a top-level R expression is printed is controlled by the global boolean variable R_Visible. This is set (to true or false) on entry to all primitive and internal functions based on the eval column of the table in file src/main/names.c: the appropriate setting can be extracted by the macro PRIMPRINT.

and

> Internal and primitive functions force the documented setting of R_Visible on return, unless the C code is allowed to change it (the exceptions above are indicated by PRIMPRINT having value 2).

So it would seem that you cannot force invisible returns from primitive generics like `[`, `length`, etc., and you must resort to workarounds like the one suggested by Alex.

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks for providing this information.